# JAVA com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 13 and error message 'command find requires authentication'

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

> com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 13 and
>   error message 'command find requires authentication'

How to create a mongo client using a password in java.

I know there was method like this:

```
public MongoClient(final ServerAddress addr, final List<MongoCredential> credentialsList);
```

But it is shown as deprecated, there is another method which requires MongoClientOptions:

```
public MongoClient(final ServerAddress addr, final MongoCredential credential, final MongoClientOptions options)
```

But I do not have any options to send. So, is there any way I can create mongo client in java using a password?

Answer (score 2):

For the find command to execute, you need to authenticate with mongo first.
An example of how you may be doing authentication:

```
Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
DB db = mongo.getDB("testdb");

boolean auth = db.authenticate("testdb", "password".toCharArray());
if (auth) {

    DBCollection table = db.getCollection("user");

    BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
    document.put("name", "mkyong");
    table.insert(document);

    System.out.println("Login is successful!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Login is failed!");
}
```

This should work fine for you.

You can check the example code in this article: https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-authentication-access-to-mongodb/

When using the mongo-java-driver the following would be appropriate:
- note this is not using the deprecated method anymore, but setting the writeconcern to Journaled (which is recommended)

```
String username = "test";
String database = "something";
String password = "secret";

MongoCredential mongoCredential = MongoCredential.createCredential(username, database, password.toCharArray());
MongoClientOptions options = MongoClientOptions.builder()
.writeConcern(WriteConcern.JOURNALED).build();

MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("host1", 27017), Arrays.asList(mongoCredential), options);
```

Comment: I am not sure which external mongo db driver you have mentioned, but I am using mongo-java-driver  and in it there is no authenticate() function available on database.

Below is how I access database:
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(mongoDBdatabase);
  MongoCollection<Document> metadata_collection = getMetadataCollectionName(database, type);

Comment: Could you give me your maven dependency?

Comment: <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
      <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.0<</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: I updated my answer to include the solution, this way it can be read in java code

Comment: new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("host1", 27017), Arrays.asList(mongoCredential)) is deprecated. This is the reason, i cannot use this way. I already mentioned this in question :)

Comment: Hi Deepak, Sorry I wasn't paying to attention, I have rewritten my solution to contain the new not deprecated method, is this what you are looking for? - Sorry for the late response

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **MongoDB Atlas**, then you have to give access to the DB for the given Role of a db user.

The issue is mainly because of the permissions not given to the user to access it.